# i want unique BillNum but when i use Note column in select it return the billNum three time

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I want unique BillNum but when I use Note column in select it return the billNum three time

I tried this query:

```
select distinct finalBillSum,
                BillNum,
                purchaseDate,
                supName,
                Note 
           from purchaseInvoice
          where purchaseDate >= '2017-09-24' and 
                purchaseDate <= '2017-09-24' 
       group by finalBillSum,
                BillNum,
                purchaseDate,
                supName,
                Note
```

this the output

```
finalBillSum    BillNum   purchaseDate      supName      Note
12230.463        5          2017-09-24       ahmed  
361.270          4          2017-09-24       ahmed  
40.000           3          2017-09-24         الاء 
46.000           2          2017-09-24         الاء 
6.840            6          2017-09-24       ahmed  
6.840            6          2017-09-24       ahmed       ملاحظة 1
6.840            6          2017-09-24       ahmed       ملاحظة 2
```

Comment: You have three distinct notes. It is correct to get three records for BillNum = 6

Comment: I went to Return one bilNum Regardless using Note

Comment: Then do not add Note to your query

Comment: i use note in select to show it in datagridview

Comment: @fatima I'd argue that you should normalize your database: move notes out into a different table, and have one row per one BillNum in your main table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want unique `BillNum` and you use `Group By`, that must be the only column that you use for the `Group By`, otherwise it's possible that you get repeating `BillNum`(because other columns are different). In this case the `Note` was different. Maybe it's sufficient to remove this column from the `GROUP BY`. Or maybe you want to aggretate the other columns like with `SUM(finalBillSum)`. Then you calculate the sum for each group.

```
SELECT finalBillSum = SUM(finalBillSum),
       BillNum
       PurchaseDate,
       SupName = MIN(SupName),
       Note = MIN(Note)
From purchaseInvoice
WHERE PurchaseDate >= '2017-09-24' and PurchaseDate <= '2017-09-24' 
GROUP BY BillNum, PurchaseDate
```

Comment: thanks but it give me 
this  Operand data type nvarchar(max) is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: @fatima You shouldn't store money as strings. If you need to store currency, you should store it separately from the amount.

Comment: SELECT finalBillSum ,
       BillNum
       PurchaseDate,
       SupName = MIN(SupName),
       Note = MIN(Note)
From purchaseInvoice
WHERE PurchaseDate >= '2017-09-24' and PurchaseDate <= '2017-09-24' 
GROUP BY BillNum, PurchaseDate,finalBillSum